# Amazon sns topic sqs labmda

Tags: aws-lambda, push-notification, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I already find out how to publish message to SNS topic and subscription are mobile notification.

But I also want every message save to a database.
How could I do this with?

Because I know that you can subscribe sqs queue also to the same topic.
But I don't only want save the message, but also who receive the message.

Please could anyone help me what is logical to do?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have an SNS topic set up you could set up a Lambda Function as a trigger for it. [SNS to Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html). [Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html)

This lambda could then be set up relatively easily to post data to a dynamodb table [Lambda to Dynamo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html). This way you wont have to set up any SQS Queues and the Lambda can be used to format and organize the data before it gets sent to Dynamo (if needed).

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for your answer. So If I made a trigger on the topic with lambda, could he see also every message who I sent to? So I want to save the message and also who receive the message.

Comment: I think if you want to record who is receiving the message you have a couple of options and it really depends how you are creating your SNS in the first place. If possible I would add an extra step before sending any data to SNS that saves the information before even going to SNS. Maybe consider using a Lambda at the start of the process that saves the data to Dynamo (or wherever) and sends it to SNS in the same function. You could then build it out as a transaction so that the data is only saved to Dynamo if the SNS is successful. Something like the picture above maybe